# Does EC2 Instance in Private subnet need Nat Gateway on this architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm planning this architecture bellow. My question is, does this architecture need Nat Gateway in order to the EC2 instance can reach by user? [My Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UOr1.png)

Comment: The answer is no, you can test it by creating ngw and installing nginx on your ec2, then delete ngw and access to ALB.

Answer (score 2):

NAT Gateway is only for the EC2 instance to be able to reach outside of the VPC, like to download security updates. A NAT Gateway is not involved in outside connections being able to initiate connections to the EC2 instance.

In your diagram, the outside connections will connect to a public load balancer. The load balancer will then be able to connect to the private EC2 instance. There should be no issue serving traffic through the load balancer without a NAT.